# Closing child froms in MDI form in c sharp

Tags: c#

I create new froms with same instant in c sharp button click event. But all have different names. I store those names in an array.

At last i need to close some selected froms in the MDI. How can i do that..?

```
private List<string> FormName = new List<string>();
private Form newPersonForm = null;
```

in click event()

```
{
    personId = getFromOutside;
    if(FormName.contains(personId))
    {
        here i need to close the form related to the person id ?
    }
    else
    {
        newPersonForm = new Form();
        newPersonFrom.Name=personId;
        FormName.add(personId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
// Assume that your parent window is parentForm
// When you are creating each form, add it to parentForm's owned forms
// Let's say you're creating form1

MyForm form1 = new MyForm();
parentForm.AddOwnedForm(form1);//if you're in your parentForm's class use this.AddOwnedForm(form1);
form1.Show();

// then when you want to close all of them simple call the below code

foreach(Form form in parentForm.OwnedForms)
{
      form.Close();
}

// And also you can call this if you're in parentForm's class
foreach(Form form in this.OwnedForms)
{
      form.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Store `Form` objects, not `string`:

```
private List<Form> Forms = new List<Form>();
```

handler:

```
personId = getFromOutside;
var existingForm = Forms.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == personId);
if(existingForm != null)
{
    existingForm.Close();
    Forms.Remove(existingForm);
}
else
{
    newPersonForm = new Form();
    newPersonFrom.Name=personId;
    Forms.Add(newPersonForm);
}
```

Comment: var existingForm = Forms.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Name == personId); what is this does.......?

Comment: @samadhi, it is LINQ expression which locates form with a given name. You can do the same using regular `foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

Inside button click event

```
{
    personId = getFromOutside;
    if(FormName.contains(personId))
    {
        //here i need to close the form related to the person id ?

        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (f.Text == personId.ToString()) //  compare Name of the Form
            {
                f.Close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        newPersonForm = new Form();
        newPersonFrom.Name=personId;
        FormName.add(personId);
    }
}
```